# WooCommerce - get Geo-IP location working for custom region/province

Tags: woocommerce, geolocation, geoip

I have added Northern Ireland as a country to WooCommerce for shipping reasons. For those unfamiliar, Northern Ireland, along with the Republic of Ireland, makeup the island of Ireland but Northern Ireland is a member of the United Kingdom *(a province of the UK I think is the official designation)*.

WooCommerce groups England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland under the ISO 3166-1 code of GB / United Kingdom. It is a pain for handling shipping between RoI, NI and the UK mainland

So... I added Northern Ireland as a country in my store with the custom ISO code of "GB-NIR". While GB-NIR is a valid [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:GB#Countries_and_province) code, WooCommerce recognises only ISO 3166-1 codes so geolocation / geo-IP doesn't work for visitors from Northern Ireland - e.g. the country field isn't automatically set to "Northern Ireland" at checkout, etc... I assume IP addresses from Northern Ireland visitors will mostly identify as UK IP addresses with the ISO code of "GB" and I wouldn't expect any IP database to utilise GB-NIR.

Is there anywhere I can say write a rule so that all IP addresses identifying as GB / United Kingdom are mapped in WooCommerce to my custom country of GB-NIR / Northern Ireland? United Kingdom isn't in use in my store *(shipping to RoI and NI only, not UK mainland)* so there's no issue shoehorning all UK IP addresses into Northern Ireland

Any thoughts how I might approach this?

Comment: If your store is focused on RoI and NI only then why not set **Default customer address** to **Shop base address**? [WooCommerce Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/#section-1)

Comment: On the other hand you can use `woocommerce_customer_default_location_array` to filter out `$location` array and check for `$location['country']` to see if it's UK and set GB-NIR if yes.

Comment: Thanks @DhavalShah, will have a look at the location_array hook. Re. setting the store to "Shop base address"... this would show Ireland (as in RoI) at checkout, shipping calculation, etc. by default. I'd like to have Northern Ireland selected if the visitor is from NI... one less thing for the customer to click and I can use the correctly selected country for VAT exemptions, shipping options and the like later on